# Android : How to create images for different sizes and densities?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an image view which has different size on normal and large sized screens(I achived it via dimens.xml), lets assume 100*100 dp on small and 133*133 dp on large sized screen.

I'm setting image to it programatically, let's say it is **def.png**

Now for best performance I should create 6 versions of def.png(assuming i cater only to mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi densities)

1. small-mdpi - 100*100 px
2. small-hdpi - 150*150 px
3. small-xhdpi - 200*200 px
4. large-mdpi - 133*133 px
5. large-hdpi - 199*199 px
6. large-xhdpi - 266*266 px

It means 6 def.png images, but I can put 3 of them because only 3 folders are available i.e. **drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi**.

*How should I achieve best performance so that there will be less scaling up and down of Images ??*

**or**

*If it is not possible this way, then what are the alternatives ?*

Comment: You normally use differently named drawable folders. Same resource name in all folders. Nothing to be done programmatically.

Comment: I'm using different drawable folders but as I've told how I can put small-hdpi and large-hdpi image in same drawable-hdpi folder??

Comment: You can't. Or you can use a different name for your file. I.e.: by adding "_150" and "_199" (respectively) to the file names. But why don't you want to use `-small-hdpi` and `-large-hdpi` for your drawable folder names, instead?

Comment: @Rotwang i'm setting image to image view programmatically, I already know that images of different resolutions should be put in different folders, It is perfectly okay if i have image view of fixed size over all devices but problem occurs if size of my image view varies with size of screen.

Comment: is it possible to use small-hdpi and large-hdpi as folder name ?

Comment: And what do you think we are talking about? Different images for different screens. Why not? I mean, I don't know ALL the possible combinations of words, you should search on android-developers. Or experiment a bit. But "by nose", it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

How to Support Multiple Screens:-

- Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your
  application supports
- Provide different layouts for different screen
  sizes
- Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen
  densities

Source :- https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support